# Store data in variable and be sure it is not interpreted when passed to a command

Tags: bash, variables, awk, hive, sqoop

I am using a bash script to launch a Sqoop to offload Oracle table to Hive.
Tables I need to ingest are indicated in a file, with this format:

```
rdbSchema|rbdTable|hiveSchema|hiveTable|col_name|1|select * from rdbSchema.rbdTable where ....|col1='varchar(1000)',col2='decimal(10)',...
```

fields are pretty clear, I just want to point out that:

1. the **query** field is usually very long, and can also contain special chars like ( ) , \ ' "
2. last column contains the datatype to use in Hive, and will contain special charas as shown in the example above

I am using awk to split this line into arguments to feed Sqoop with, and I want/need to continue with it.
The Sqoop command is contained in a function. I `cat` the file containing the tables, pipe it to `xargs` which calls the function passing it the whole line. Then, the function uses `awk` as shown below to calculate the arguments. I use xargs so I can parallelize the ingestion.

For example look at the way I pass `$query` to my script. I experienced yesterday that a query containing something like select col1, (select col2 from ...) from ... (forgive the syntax, I'm not a DBA) will be mispelled by Bash. It happened just yesterday, with a query containing also a single quote.
Since I've been asked to implement this new fild, which I know in advance would be a mess about chars (since it will for sure contain single quotes, double quotes, and parenthesis), I want to know how to correctly handle it

This is how I split my values ATM:

```
wtf=$1
local origSchema=$(echo "$wtf" | awk -F"|" '{print $1}')
local origTable=$(echo "$wtf" | awk -F"|" '{print $2}')
local hiveSchema=$(echo "$wtf" | awk -F"|" '{print $3}')
local hiveTable=$(echo "$wtf" | awk -F"|" '{print $4}')
local splitColumn=$(echo "$wtf" | awk -F"|" '{print $5}')
local sqoopParallels=$(echo "$wtf" | awk -F"|" '{print $6}')
local query=$(echo "$wtf" | awk -F"|" '{print $7}')
local query+=' WHERE $CONDITIONS'
local types=   --> HERE I NEED TO PARSE THE LAST COLUMN ADDED <--
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

## EDIT

As asked by Ed Morton, this is how I invoke the Sqoop command inside the script.

```
 sqoop import \
  -Dmapred.child.java.opts="-Djava.security.egd="file:/dev/../dev/urandom" " \
  -Dmapred.job.queuename="$yarnQueue" \
  -Dmapreduce.job.name=$quote"$jobName"$quote \
  --connect "$origServer" \
  --username "$username" \
  --password-file file://"$passwordFile" \
  --delete-target-dir \
  --target-dir "$targetTmpHdfsDir"/"$hiveTable" \
  --outdir "$dirJavaCode" \
  --hive-database "$hiveSchema" \
  --hive-table "$hiveTable" \
  --hive-partition-key "$hivePartitionName" \
  --hive-partition-value "$hivePartitionValue" \
  --query "$query" \
  --hive-import \
  --null-string "''" \
  --null-non-string "''" \
  --num-mappers 1 \
  --map-column-hive --> Here I need to add the new field <--
  --fetch-size 1000000 &>> "$logFileRaw"
```

Comment: Sqoop command added. Thanks

Comment: It is a java property I need to pass to Sqoop exactly how it is written. Maybe there's a better solution, however I used that because bash was interpreting " and : . It is actually working as supposed.

Comment: And yes, the way I pass `$query` ATM is not the best solution, and it is exploding in case of special chars like )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143426/discussion-between-omar-and-ed-morton).

Comment: As I said, I'm launching the command inside a function, that is called by xargs. Here is the command `grep -Ev '^#|^$' "$listOfTables" | xargs -d '\n' -l1 -I args -P$parallels bash -c "doSqoop 'args'"`
What I do inside the function is parsing the line, some controls, and then launch the command stated above

Comment: That is the missing piece of the puzzle. Please updated your question to include that extremely important part and show the definition of the function `doSqoop`.